# Add Bootstrape Tooltip in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Component,AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as b from 'bootstrap';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

import { CalendarService } from './calendar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css']
})
export class Calendar implements AfterViewInit  {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      jQuery(element).toolTip({title: event.title});
  }
}
```

So in this `jQuery(element).toolTip({title: event.title});`, I am getting TypeScript error on `.toolTip` Property:

> 'toolTip' does not exist on type 'JQuery'"

Comment: are you using cli ? if so take a look at this [third party js](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-bootstrap.](http://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples)
Try not to use jQuery in angular2+. Of course if you must.

Answer (score 0):

integrate bootstarp in your project [bootstrap integration](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-bootstrap-with-angular-c83c3cee3f4a)

Then use bootstarp tooltip
use can refer : [bootstrap tooltip](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/web_development/9781785882340/8/ch08lvl1sec50/bootstrap-tooltip-component)

[plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/gjnRxnmk0IqG0gSVlCQg/)